# Are $L_\infty$ functions measurable/integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces, lebesgue-measure, ergodic-theory

Lemma 2.6 of of Einsiedler & Ward's *Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number Theory* (p.15) involves:

$$
\int f d\mu,
$$

where $f \in \mathcal{L}^{\infty}$.

The measure $\mu$ could be the Lebesgue measure and $f$ could be a non-integrable but limited function on $[0,1]$ (like the classic example for not Lebesgue integrable, the indicator function of representatives of equivalence classes of reals over rationals). In this case the given integral is meaningless. Where am I wrong?

Comment: \mathcal{L} -> $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: $L_\infty([0,1])$ is the space of all essentially bounded, measurable functions on the interval.  This answers both your questions: the integral makes sense because the functions are measurable and it is finite because the interval has finite measure, so $L_\infty \subset L_1$.

Comment: More generally, $L_\infty(\mu)$ on a measure space $(X,\mu)$ is the space of all essentially bounded, measurable functions on the space.  If I remember correctly, all spaces in E-W are finite measure spaces, so in all these cases $L_\infty \subset L_1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the paragraph above Lemma 2.6, the authors explicitly state "[we write] $\mathcal L^\infty$ for the space of measurable bounded functions"